# Random forest visualization Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, feature-selection, random-forest, importance

For a dataset I ran a random forest model with sikit learn. When I checked important variables from RF , I was unable to understand the reason for choosing that variable as important.  In my understanding There would be rules for the tree built by RF. Is there a way to visualize the trees and understand the rules. Or how can I know the reason on choosing that variable as important by RF